# Login verification in c

Tags: c

I am using a `signed long long int` to count the number of digits entered by the user. The program should repeatedly asking for input if the ID and Pin is incorrect and display 'successfully login' when the correct ID and Pin is entered. However, when I entered the correct ID and Pin, the program keeps asking for input over and over again. What I did wrong in my code? Help is much appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long n = 1234567,m = 123456;
    int count = 0, count2 = 0, c, a;

    do
    {
        printf("Enter student ID: ");
        scanf("%lli", &n);

        while (n != 0)
        {
            n /= 10;
            ++count;
        }

        if (count < 7 || count > 8)
            printf("The Student ID should be in 7 or 8 digits, please try again\n");

    } while(n != 1234567);


    do
    {
        printf("Enter security pin: ");
        scanf("%lli", &m);
        {
            c = a;
            a++;
        }

    while (m != 0)
    {
        m /= 10;
        ++count2;
    }

    if (count2 < 6 || count2 > 6) 
        printf("Please enter a 6-digit pin\n");

    if (a == 5)
    {
        printf("\nAccess Denied\n");
    }

    } while (m != 123456);

    if (n == 1234567 && m == 123456)
        printf("Successfully Login\n");
    else
        printf("Wrong password, try again\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try stepping through in your debugger

Comment: ID's and PIN's would probably be better entered as a string of digits, rather than ints!

Comment: You're destroying the value of `n` in the while loop. It will never equal 1234567, but will always equal zero

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is with the logic :

```
scanf("%lli", &n);
while (n != 0)
        {
            n /= 10;
            ++count;
        }
```

even though the user has given a correct student ID as n=1234567 in the scanf, It gets divided here as n=n/10 ---> which will assign n=123456. In the code the n and m values will never be equal to the correct values because of the while loop logic. The same applies for the password too.
If you want to check the password length and the ID length, Its better to use strings along with atoi function.